# Angular seed or yeoman with generator-angular-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator

Should I still use angular seed or is better to use something like yeoman with generator-angular-fullstack?

Thank you!

Regards, Sandor

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends entirely on the scope of your application. Angular Seed is good (though a bit outdated) because it gives you a pretty minimal structure to work with (if that's what you need). Yeoman can be nice because it gives you a ton of stuff already built in like structure, grunt, bower, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Angular.JS team, Angular Seed was conceived on a plane ride and does not reflect best practices.

I made [this comparison](http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/) of things you can use to start an application with Angular.JS.  I would recommend picking one of those.